# Isolate bootstrap CSS to one angular component?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

Is it possible to isolate Bootstrap's css file to one Angular component?

When including the file globally in `styles.css` or in `.angular-cli.json`, the global styles are causing issues with other components that should not be using bootstrap. I have tried to do this by importing it from the component's CSS file but the styles do not seem to render properly...

I am using Angular 5 and Angular Cli 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

you can explicitly set the encapsulation strategy using the encapsulation property.Set it to `ViewEncapsulation.Native` for your case

```
@Component({
// ...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
styles: [
  // ...
]
})
export class HelloComponent {
// ...
}
```

Native - styles from main HTML do not propagate to the component. Styles defined in this component's @Component decorator are scoped to this component only.
Refer this [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).

Comment: When trying this, the component does not render at all, any ideas?

Comment: That should not happen what is the error you get on browser's console if possible share your code?

Comment: Ah looks like it's not supported in the newest version of firefox... TypeError: hostEl.createShadowRoot is not a function. Any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: This approach worked for me, I couldn't find any other approach.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Use ---> encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

Comment: this worked for me, but with shadowDom, thank you..